# Why does the mass-energy associated with nuclear potentials obey $m = \gamma m_0$?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, potential

Here is a thought experiment that has me confused.

Imagine a particle, the nonexiston. If possible, ignore quantum mechanics and let the nonexiston be a classical particle with spooky action at a distance.

The nonexiston has a field that exerts huge forces on other nonexistons. The nonexiston field is an inverse square field. An isolated nonexiston has a very tiny rest mass $m_n$, but a pair of nonexistons separated by $r_0$ has a large associated potential of $V = M c^2$ such that their combined mass-energy is $m_0 =M + 2m_n \gg m_n$

We accelerate the pair of nonexistons from $0$ to $v$ while holding their proper length of separation constant and try to predict how much energy we will need. Without assuming *a priori* that field energy counts as mass, can we prove it will be $(\gamma-1)(m_0)c^2$?

Yes.

- The nonexiston field is inverse-square dependent so the separation potential is $V\propto r^{-1}$ dependent.
- Increasing velocity from $0$ to $v$ length-contracts the separation distance by $1/\gamma(v)$
- Therefore increasing velocity from $0$ to $v$ increases the separation energy of the nonexistons, as measured by the original rest frame, by a factor of $(1/\gamma(v))^{-1} = \gamma$.
- $V = \gamma Mc^2$
- $E = V + 2\gamma m_n c^2 = \gamma(M+2m_n)c^2 = \gamma m_0c^2$

So far so good. Relativity is internally consistent if we make the nonexiston field one for which potential goes as $1/r$.

But what if we make the nonexiston potential vary like that of the strong nuclear force?

$V \propto e^{-B r}/r$

Now we should get (for some constants $A$ and $B$)

$E = \gamma(Ae^{-B r_0/\gamma}/r_0 + 2m_n c^2)$

Which is very much *not* $\gamma m_0c^2$

What's going on? I feel like I must be missing something.

---

I realized later that I packed a variable (mass) into one of my constants (B). If we assume that that means $B' = \gamma B$ then $V = \gamma V_0$ and $m = \gamma m_0$ for $\vec r \parallel \vec v$, which is just as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Increasing velocity from 0 to v length-contracts the separation distance by $1/γ(v)$

I think your first error is here. Length contraction only takes place along the dimension parallel to motion.

Suppose your molecule of di-nonexiston is at rest and we accelerate towards it instead. Your length- contraction approach predicts that an observer moving parallel to the inter-nonexiston axis would measure a different effective mass than an observer moving at the same speed in a perpendicular direction. If your molecule is rotating, would a moving observer see its relativistic mass fluctuate?

In electromagnetism, these issues are resolved by coming up with rules for transformation of the electric and magnetic fields under boosts.

Comment: You're right and this makes sense. Do we have an analogous transformation rule for the nuclear force?

Comment: In quantum field theory, behavior under Lorentz transformations is a major factor in constraining the form of any field, including the fields associated with the short-range strong and weak forces.

Answer (score 2):

Separation distance is parallel to motion:

Increasing velocity from 0 to v length-contracts the separation distance by 1/γ(v)

Increasing velocity from 0 to v multiplies the force that is associated with the potential energy, which is associated with the potential, by 1.  (Because from basic special relativity we know that transformation of forces parallel to motion is: F'=F)

From those two effects we can see that the potential changes by 1/γ(v).

Separation distance is perpendicular to motion:

Increasing velocity from 0 to v length-contracts the separation distance by 1.

Increasing velocity from 0 to v multiplies the force that is associated with the potential energy which is associated with the potential, by 1/γ(v). (Because from basic special relativity we know that transformation of forces perpendicular to motion is: F'=F/γ(v) )

From those two effects we can see that the potential changes by 1/γ(v).

Notice that we did not need to know how the force depends on the distance.

Comment: So - in the perpendicular case we don't need to know how the potential varies with distance, but in the parallel case we do. How then do we deal with a potential that doesn't vary as $1/r$ in the parallel (or partly parallel) case? Are we back to the issue pointed out in Rob's answer where we've set up a particle whose mass would change as it rotates?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter and all the real forces in the universe satisfy $V = \gamma V_0$ for $\vec F \parallel \vec v$. I realized I packed a mass term into one of my constants, detail added at the end of my OP.

Comment: @gs Energy difference from A to B is the sum of the lengths of small segments of line A-> B multiplied by forces on each segment.              Same thing in another frame that agrees with the forces but disagrees  with the lengths of the small segments is the same, except that the length of each small segment is divided by gamma.  So the energy in the latter case is 1/gamma times the energy in the first case. And frames agree about the forces in the parallel case.